# why suppress Error in Rmarkdown doesn't work?

Tags: r, error-handling, r-markdown, knitr, sweave

I want to supress Errors in Rmw files. So, i've tried to set the global chunk option `error=TRUE`, but it doesn't work. Also it doesn't work to set the chunk option `error=TRUE` directly in the chunk.
Here is an example code:

```
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

abc 
<<setup, cache=F, include=F>>=
library(knitr)
library(formatR)
opts_chunk$set(error=TRUE)
knit_hooks$set(error=TRUE)
@

<<a,error=TRUE>>=
A <- 5
# of course, that doesnt work, but i want the error message as chunk output
A * B
@
\end{document}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work

Only the error message:
"Error in eval(expr, .GlobalEnv) : object 'L' not found"
appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using `Sweave` from base R rather than `knitr`.  If you were using `knitr`, you'd get a warning about the `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` statement.

If you are using RStudio, this is one of the Project Options.  If you are running things directly, run `knitr::knit("<your filename>")`, instead of `Sweave("<your filename>")`.

There are a couple of other errors that will stop `knitr` from working; this version fixes them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

abc 
<<setup, cache=F, include=F>>=
library(knitr)
library(formatR)
opts_chunk$set(error=TRUE)
@

<<a,error=TRUE>>=
A <- 5
# of course, that doesnt work, but i want the error message as chunk output
A * B
@
\end{document}
```

The changes were:

- You need the `\documentclass` line at the start.
- You don't want the `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` statement.
- You don't want the `knit_hooks$set(error=TRUE)` statement.